# Linking SharePoint database with ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, attribute-joins, hyperlink, sharepoint

The organization I am working for has a sharepoint database that multiple people update every time they do an inspection of natural resources on a parcel in the county.

This database has the following fields:

*Parcel Number

*Date

*Notes

*Inspector

*Action

I have created a feature class with a centroid with these attributes placed in each parcel that has been inspected.

Is there a way to dynamically link the sharepoint database to the geodatabase so that when they go in and change/add anything to the notes section it actively changes (and adds new points to newly listed parcels) the attributes in the featureclass?

If not, his layer only needs to be updated monthly. I am able to export it to a excel or csv file. Is there a quick way to create the centroids layer from this table?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Query Layers.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_a_query_layer/00s50000000n000000/)

- Load your parcel boundary layer into ArcMap
- Pull the information you require from your back-end Sharepoint into a stand-alone table in ArcMap (including the ID field that joins it to the Parcel)
- Make a [join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002n000000) between from the parcel layer to the query layer.
- I believe that this link should now be dynamic and will pull the data directly from the db behind Sharepoint.

Any attributes within the fields that you have pulled in from Sharepoint that get changed at the SP end, these should flow through to your MXD.

A less dynamic approach would be suck the data you want out of Sharepoint, into an XLS, and load the XLS into your MXD and then join your parcel layer to that.

You have not given any background into the bigger picture on what you are trying to achieve.  You may want to take a look at [ArcGIS for Sharepoint](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/mapping-sharepoint/key-functionality.html).

I might be missing something, but I do not see the need to calculate centroids everytime.  Do the parcel boundaries change from month to month?